# Manipulate row values of subset dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` like this:

```
    ID1    ID2
0   foo    bar
1   fizz   buzz
```

And another `df2` like this:

```
    ID1    ID2    Count    Code   
0   abc    def      7        B
1   fizz   buzz     5        B
2   fizz1  buzz2    9        C
3   foo    bar      6        B
4   foo    bar      6        Z
```

What I would like to do is filter the second dataframe where `ID1` and `ID2` match a row in the first dataframe,  as a dataframe `sub_df`, then apply following code `sub_df.loc[sub_df["Count"] >= 5, "Code"] = "A"` to `sub_df`:

sub_df:

```
    ID1    ID2    Count    Code   
1   fizz   buzz     5        B
3   foo    bar      6        B
4   foo    bar      6        Z
```

Finaly I  would like to yield a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
    ID1    ID2    Count    Code   
0   abc    def      7        B
1   fizz   buzz     5        A
2   fizz1  buzz2    9        C
3   foo    bar      6        A
4   foo    bar      6        A
```

How could I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test membership between combinations of `ID1` and `ID2` with joined both columns with [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
id2 = df2['ID1'].str.cat(df2['ID2'], sep='_')
id1 = df1['ID1'].str.cat(df1['ID2'], sep='_')

df2.loc[(df2["Count"] >= 5) & id2.isin(id1), "Code"] = "A" 
print (df2)
     ID1    ID2  Count Code
0    abc    def      7    B
1   fizz   buzz      5    A
2  fizz1  buzz2      9    C
3    foo    bar      6    A
4    foo    bar      6    A
```

EDIT:

Tested and for me working nice:

```
print (df1)
    ID1   ID2
0   foo   bar
1  fizz  buzz

print (df2)
     ID1    ID2        date  price
0    abc    def  2019-08-01      1
1   fizz   buzz  2019-08-02      2
2  fizz1  buzz2  2019-08-02      3
3    foo    bar  2019-08-03      4
4    foo    bar  2019-08-01      5

df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date"])
df2.loc[(df2["date"] != '2019-08-01') & (df2['ID1'].isin(df1['ID1'])), "price"] = np.nan, 
print (df2)
     ID1    ID2       date  price
0    abc    def 2019-08-01    1.0
1   fizz   buzz 2019-08-02    NaN <- set NaN beacuse id
2  fizz1  buzz2 2019-08-02    3.0
3    foo    bar 2019-08-03    NaN <- set NaN beacuse id
4    foo    bar 2019-08-01    5.0 <- not set NaN beacuse id but 2019-08-01
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify two things: my real data`df2` is already merge from `df1`, I don't want to merge again; `df1`'s column `ID1`, which is unique and could role as `index`,  it's a sub set of `ID1` in `df2`.

Comment: @ahbon - I try explain. Here left join is used only for indicator column, edited answer for better output.

Comment: If I want select subset by one column `ID1` from `df1`, can I simply `tolist` this column and then use `isin`?

Comment: @ahbon - Then change `id2.isin(id1)` to `df2['ID1'].isin(df2['ID1'])`

Comment: `df2.loc[(df2["date"] != '2019-08-01') & (df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])), "price"] = np.nan`, I try to set `price` of subset of `df2` as `np.nan`, whose `id` is in `id` of `df1`, except for date of `2019-08-01`, but result is all price values are `nan`s, what wrong with my code here?

Comment: It's very werid, my data still not working. Is there other method to do same as `df2["date"] != '2019-08-01'` maybe `notin` or `~`?

Comment: I try with this: `df2.loc[(~df4["date"].isin(['2019-08-01'])) & (df2['ID1'].isin(df1['ID1'])), "price"] = np.nan`, it works.

Answer (score 3):

You could [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both dataframes with an `indicator` and use it to set a `Code` as `A` or not:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on=['ID1','ID2'], indicator='ind')
df.loc[(df["Count"] >= 5) & (df['ind'] == 'both'), "Code"] = "A" 
df = df.drop('ind', axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df2)

     ID1    ID2  Count Code
0    abc    def      7    B
1   fizz   buzz      5    A
2  fizz1  buzz2      9    C
3    foo    bar      6    A
4    foo    bar      6    A
```

Comment: If `df2` is already merge from `df1`, I don't want to merge again, how to do it?

Comment: Yes but it is necessary to merge to know which rows are the same @ahbon

Comment: Yes, but I get duplicated columns, maybe should merge with `cols_to_use = df2.columns - df.columns`, and then `df = df2.merge(df1[cols_to_use], how='left', on=['ID1','ID2'], indicator='ind').
`